# SSRS 2008 - Error: Subreport could not be shown

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have used SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio to create a Reporting Services 2008 project. Everything was moving right along until I tried to create a subreport, which led me to the familiar error:

> Error: Subreport could not be shown

Yep, the main report and subreport work if run seperately. When I add the subreport to the main report, the main report runs fine and the subreport returns the error.

Both reports are run from seperate stored procedures. The data source which drives both reports contains both procedures.

The subreport has a single parameter. I have tried testing a static value, so I've added the parameter (right click on the subreport, select Properties, chose the Parameters tab, and added the correct parameter name with a value of =(16102)).

If I add a subreport that has no parameters to the main report - the subreport just prints a string, for testing purposes - then that subreport displays correctly.

Any words of wisdom?

Comment: What area of the report did you place the subreport?

Comment: I have placed the subreport at the top of the main report so I can see if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. My solution was to use the right project type. I missed the "Business Intelligence Projects" at the top of the list of new project types, and instead was using Visual Basic\Reporting\Reports Application. When I use the BIP/Report Server Project project type, then I was able to get the subreports to be displayed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue,

> Error: Subreport could not be shown

My issue was caused by the subreport being run using a Snapshot.  As soon as I disabled the snapshot, everything worked.

Looks like Snapshots are not compatible in Subreports.

Hope this helps someone else.